# network connection error

Tags: networking, server, samba

I recently had to upgrade my ubuntu text-only server from 16.04 to 18.04. It was a complete install from scratch due to disk failure. Although I can see my network shares in Windows Explorer it appears as if the connection is dropped and immediately restored. The messages in kern.log are:

```
ata8.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ata8.00: cmd 61/00:f0:20:65:f3/0a:00:07:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 1310720 out 
         res 40/00:b8:f8:ec:f3/00:00:07:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
```

This message is repeated a few times and then the following appears:

```
ata8: hard resetting link
ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata8.00: configured for UDMA/33
ata8: EH complete
```

It appears as if the share is dropped and reconnected almost immediately and this happens only when a Windows machine is connected to the network. I've chased the problem in the forums and followed all advice but it seems this is an ongoing problem. The 16.04 server never had this issue but I have found posts from people with this problem running 16.04 servers. So I'd prefer to stick with 18.04.

So far I've disabled avahi, tried NFS and removed it, and played with samba with no luck. It seems the problem lies with samba because apache is not experiencing any disruptions. I have a number of browser apps installed on the server and none have indicated any connection drops.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Events subsequent to my post pointed to another damaged disk and not samba. The network connectivity problem appears to have been corrected with a recent update and serendipity masked the disk defect. Fsck confirmed the damaged disk and a lengthy and uninterrupted process across the network confirmed that connectivity is no longer a problem. So far so good.